# Memory error in python using numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, text-mining, lda, topic-modeling

I am getting the following error for this code:

```
model = lda.LDA(n_topics=15, n_iter=50, random_state=1)
model.fit(X)
topic_word = model.topic_word_
print("type(topic_word): {}".format(type(topic_word)))
print("shape: {}".format(topic_word.shape))
print ("\n")
n = 15
doc_topic=model.doc_topic_
for i in range(15):
    print("{} (top topic: {})".format(titles[i], doc_topic[0][i].argmax()))

topic_csharp=np.zeros(shape=[1,n])
np.copyto(topic_csharp,doc_topic[0][i])
for i, topic_dist in enumerate(topic_word):
    topic_words = np.array(vocab)[np.argsort(topic_dist)][:-(n+1):-1]
    print('*Topic {}\n- {}'.format(i, ' '.join(topic_words)))
```

error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\csharp.py", line 56, in <module>
topic_words = np.array(vocab)[np.argsort(topic_dist)][:-(n+1):-1]
MemoryError
```

The doc I am fitting into model has about 1,50,000 lines of text. 
vocab_size: 558270
n_words: 13075390 (after preprocessing)

How can I solve this error?

Comment: How much **free** RAM do you have on your computer (before you execute this python code)?

Comment: 2 GB on 8GB is free.

Comment: Can you just buy more memory?

Comment: Not feasible at the moment. :/ 
Was looking for a solution to alter the code, which would be efficient..

Answer (score 0):

If your arrays are too large for RAM, use numpy.memmap. 
See http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.memmap.html

Comment: memmap doesn't accept tuple (vocab), needs string or buffer.

Comment: True, but in the example to the link I shared it explains how you can create a temporary file as a buffer, and then you can put vocab in it. 
Your code snippet doesn't include the part where you create vocab, but you can place it directly into the np.memmap object (you'll need to determine the shape a priori when creating it). Then do the argsort on it in place. Finally, see if you can take the slice when you assign topic_words without running out of memory.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here (as quotations) and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.