# Memory error in python while adding doc to TermDocumentMatrix

Tags: python, text-mining, lda, topic-modeling

```
    tdm = textmining.TermDocumentMatrix()
with open('C:/Users/java.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        tdm.add_doc(line)
        temp = list(tdm.rows(cutoff=1))
        vocab = tuple(temp[0])
        X = np.array(temp[1:])
        titles=tuple(temp[0])
model = lda.LDA(n_topics=15, n_iter=50, random_state=1)
model.fit(X)
```

for the above code, I am getting the following error for the TermDocumentMatrix() object:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\java.py", line 40, in <module>
    tdm.add_doc(line)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\textmining\__init__.py", line 298, in add_doc
    words = self.tokenize(document)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\textmining\__init__.py", line 82, in simple_tokenize
    document = re.sub('[^a-z]', ' ', document)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\re.py", line 155, in sub
    return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
MemoryError
```

How can I solve this error where the size of this file: ('C:/Users/java.txt') is 11 GB?

Comment: Why are you re-creating the `tmp`, `vocab`, `X`, and `titles` objects for every line of the file? That's not the main issue though; you need to reduce your memory usage or get more memory. One option is to process the file line by line, saving results to disk, then re-load the data as a sparse matrix.

Comment: Try splitting the file up into a few different pieces and processing it that way.

Comment: P.S. You seem to have posted basically [the same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36454782/memory-error-in-python-using-numpy-array) within the span of an hour. Please don't do that.

Comment: It is a bit different because the question you pointed out was giving an error for numpy array and this question- an error at TermDocumentMatrix() object. I thought maybe both are different topics having different solutions. Forgive me if I misunderstood, I'm new to StackOverFlow as well as in Python.